# creating a dict from 2 given lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is a working script i wrote to build a `dictionary` from 2 given lists: the `i-th` object in `L1` is a `key` to `value` located in the `i-th` place of `L2`.

```
L1=[1,2,'a','b']
L2=[(22,'aa'),['x'],('3',),('s',3)]

d = {}

sizeL = len(L1)
for i in range(sizeL):
    key = L1[i]
    val = L2[i]
    d[key] = val

print "Output:\n"
print "\nL1=",L1
print "L2=",L2
print "dictionary d = ",d
```

I want to try it in different way: by using `dict` function. Therefore, i need to creat a list with tuples i guess. I cant understand how. this is what i try:

```
L1=[1,2,'a','b']
L2=[(22,'aa'),['x'],('3'),('s','3')]
L=[]
n=len(L1)

for i in range(n):
    L.append(L1[i],L2[i])    
d=dict(L)
print d
```

Ofcourse i get error because the wrong-using of the `append` function..

Would like to get idea how to create this "tuple list", a list that can be used by `dict` function.

thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can simply `zip` the two lists element-wise, then create a `dict` from that

```
>>> dict(zip(L1,L2))
{1: (22, 'aa'), 2: ['x'], 'a': ('3',), 'b': ('s', 3)}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
L1= [1, 2, 'a', 'b']
L2= [(22, 'aa'), ['x'], ('3',), ('s', 3)]

d = {k:v for k,v in zip(L1,L2)}
print d
```

Yields

```
{'a': ('3',), 1: (22, 'aa'), 2: ['x'], 'b': ('s', 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code it should be:

```
for i in range(n):
    L.append((L1[i],L2[i])) #append a tuple of (L1[i], L2[i])
```

But the more easier way is just to:

```
d = dict(zip(L1,L2))
```